# Flag user profile

Tags: support, profile-page, users, external-links

Is there any way to flag a part of the description or links in a user's profile?

For example, I have found a link, that might have been the domain of that user some day but the user doesn't use it anymore and it has become abandoned. So now there are only malicious ads on that site, that could infect other users when they visit that site. Is there any way to warn other users to not follow that link or have a moderator delete it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, users are allowed to put whatever they'd like on their profile (including spammy links, I *believe*). If you know they're malicious, though, you might want to contact a moderator.

You can't flag a user's profile, but you can flag one of their posts with an "other" flag and explain what's wrong; a moderator will see it and take a look at the issue.

Comment: Or even one of your own posts, if the other user doesn't have any.

Comment: @AndrewBarber sigh.... we need a better way to get in touch with mods other then through **flagging your own post**

Comment: This work-around doesn't work if the [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6319355/the-bondage-mistress) doesn't have any posts.