# Stack Overflow policy on offensive screennames

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

I know there is a lot of talk and hype about Stack Overflow becoming more user friendly (in a literal sense).

There have been several posts and blogs about becoming a place which is nicer to users, but what should we do when we come across an offensive username?

I came across a user whose name and profile picture is quite [offensive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8929031/kkkonfleek).

I see that there is a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285204/flag-user-profile) similar to mine already but the top posted answer states

> Generally, users are allowed to put whatever they'd like on their profile

I don't think that this should be the official stance for Stack Overflow.
I'd like to open this for discussion to understand stack's official stance on offensive usernames.

Also, I'd like to suggest a feature which we can flag on someones profile.

Comment: thanks for highlighting.  User's destroyed.

Comment: considering that the question linked is about links, your quote is missing context in that it's talking about links and that if you belive a link is malicious you contact a mod

Comment: Voting to reopen. The fact that we can _report_ an offensive username, is orthogonal to our _policy_ on offensive user names.

Comment: @S.L.Barth but the 2nd duplicate does point to a question with an answer that explains the policy `...but a username is visible everywhere the user posts. As such it is subject to the terms of service, which require that subscriber-provided content is not offensive.`

Comment: @Jaydles I missed what this user's profile picture and text said, but I am curious why you destroyed the user instead of resetting the user name and profile picture, especially since they have a decent question on the site. Guidance we've been given is to reset that information when valid contributions have been made.

Comment: @andy, they did? I checked twice that they had no content before deleting, since you’re right about the guidance. (FWIW the offensive content was not a borderline call, but I wouldn’t have destroyed if I’d know there was content...)

Comment: [This was their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109448/how-do-i-randomly-chooce-a-def). Good to know about the guidance though. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: So... what was the image? And the name? You can't dangle bait like this infront of me and not pay out. It's not nice.

Comment: @Will: see the link to the question - something to do with "KKK". I think I can guess roughly what the image was.

Comment: Wait, they nuked one of my sock puppet accounts? Noooooo!