# Comment custom flagged containing a user with a vulgar name auto marked as helpful

Tags: discussion, flags, comment-flags, display-names

I just custom flagged a comment containing a link to a user profile with a vulgar name on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251682/what-should-be-done-about-offensive-names?rq=1) (the post isn't really relevant to this question). I chose to custom flag the comment as the user had not made any posts. [The user in question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11388406/fuck-you)

In hindsight I probably should have thought about the instances that cause comments to be automatically marked as helpful, but I would've assumed that custom moderator flags would not get this treatment as the whole point in them is to get a moderator's attention. What was the thought process behind having this feature on the custom flags or was it just an oversight that has never been noticed before? Or was it a super speedy moderator seeing the flag instantaneously?

Comment: Does the regex for the comment script take the username as part of it?  That'd explain it, and probably an edge case.

Comment: It won't have been a super speedy mod, otherwise the user would've had the vulgarity removed...

Comment: Better flag posts for moderator attention in this case. The comment flag UI is terrible in this case. What did the comment contain, though?

Comment: When you're reporting users, flagging posts is generally better. Mod-flag auto-marked as helpful sounds as a bug though

Comment: @Zoe read the second sentence: "I chose to custom flag the comment as the user had not made any posts." Unfortunately it's not possible to flag a post that doesn't exist...

Comment: How does anybody find a user account like that from the million of existing accounts?  They have to intentionally go searching for them.  A dirty mind is a joy forever.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard read the first sentence: `[...] flagging posts [...]`. I never said the users' posts. It can be your post, it can be the first one you can find, the most recently asked question on <insert some tag you watch>, generally any post you can find as long as you explain the context and say it has nothing to do with that specific post. Those are accepted because of the lack of a [user flagging feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285204/flag-user-profile#comment150771_285205)

Comment: There is no way that a user could have posted a comment without having ever made any posts, so there would definitely be a post that you could flag. Comment flags are automatically marked as "helpful" if the associated post is deleted. This is why you should flag *posts* (questions or answers) when your intention is something other than deletion of a comment.

Comment: @CodyGray - In this case, the comment was posted about a user with no posts, but with a vulgar name. Having the vulgarity in the URL must have triggered the auto-delete regex, but that shouldn't kick in for a custom flag. Custom comment flags shouldn't be auto-cleared by the system, and I'd recommend someone file a feature request to prevent that from happening. I'm still [not totally happy with the silent auto-deletion of comments containing obscenities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284053/community-deletion-of-comments-should-raise-a-moderator-flag) because of what it can hide.

Comment: the f-word within a comment auto-deletes it when flagged. Note that if you look for the f-word in the list of users you'll get quite a lot of them (15 right now). As long as they don't post...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Then you or another moderator should remove those names from the database

Comment: well, a lot of accounts are created every day with spam descriptions. As long as they don't post anything, we don't do anything either. Renaming those profiles can be reverted by the users. We could delete the accounts, but they could re-create it... not worth... if you don't _search_ for the f-word you don't see them.

Comment: @CodyGray 1. Scenario A, you post something that gets deleted long time later, so you keep the reputation. 2. Scenario B, you submit plenty edit suggestions that give you +2 each time. 3. Scenario C, you got 100 reputation from a different Stack Exchange site. -- And the name may have been changed by the user after reaching enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: Ah, indeed, @Cœur. Look at all those open vectors of abuse! And people complain it's hard to get enough rep to comment...

Comment: @CodyGray Hard to do without becoming invested in the community.

Comment: Related meta.SE thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237342/does-flagging-a-comment-as-other-count-as-a-vote-to-delete-it

Comment: _"I probably should have thought about the instances that cause comments to be automatically marked as helpful"_ Did you mean "...that cause _flags_ to be automatically marked as helpful"? I would edit but the title says the same ("auto marked" can only refer to "comment" because "flagged" is not a noun)... After reading the discussion I'm reasonably sure that the flag was auto-marked helpful (and the comment auto-deleted) but that's not what the post says.

Comment: In such a case I would simply flag one of my own posts with a custom flag, linking to the comment. Not the way it should be, but the way it works. We could probably use a Feature Request to change this behaviour, perhaps keeping the auto deletion, but without the marking helpful.